# Unable to execute POM.XML as Maven-Install

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I am getting "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test" error when I execute my pom.xml as Maven Install, this was working fine last week and has only just started failing yesterday and today, I have not changed anything so not sure why this is happening?

My pom.xml is as follows:

4.0.0
com.tem
softwareTestingExercise14
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>
    <selenium-java.version>3.11.0</selenium-java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.${java.version}</source>
                <target>1.${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>RegressionTestRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reporting</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            
                <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please advise on how this can be resolved

Thanks for your help,

Kind Regards,

Miss Bhela

Comment: what is the fault? does it says no source to compile?

Comment: It just says "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test" there are no other errors